# isBefore unexpected issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, dayjs

have no clue why my code isnt working, ive tried everything even resorted to asking AI, still no clue. isBefore shows up orange and is defined as 'any' dont know why.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Start updating the time
        updateCurrentTime();
    
        function classTimeAdjustment() {
            
            var currentTime = dayjs();
            var tenStartTime = dayjs("9:59 AM", 'h:mm A');
            var tenEndTime = dayjs("11:00 AM", 'h:mm A');
    
            if (currentTime.isAfter(tenEndTime)) {
                $('#hour-10').removeClass("present");
                $('#hour-10').addClass("past");
            } else if (currentTime.isBefore(tenStartTime)) {
                $('#hour-10').addClass("future");
                $('#hour-10').removeClass("present");
                $('#hour-10').removeClass("past");
            } else {
                $('#hour-10').removeClass("future");
                $('#hour-10').removeClass("past");
                $('#hour-10').addClass("present");
            }
        }
    
        classTimeAdjustment(); // Call the function initially
    });
```

Expecting it to turn the bootstrap block grey for future if the time is future, but the code doesnt work. Cant use isBetween because cannot use plugin.

Comment: `shows up orange` - no indication what it would show up any particular colour - it's odd that you add/remove 3 classes in two cases, but only 2 classes for the first

Comment: Your way to create dayjs object looks weird, I think it should be `var tenStartTime = = dayjs().hour(9).minute(59)`

Comment: What i can see `tenStartTime` is null